# Mesh plot threshold in MatLab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, mesh

I am using an algorithm to determine a threshold for image analysis of nuclei in MATLAB. This algorithm measures all the pixel intensities within a nucleus and calculates a value that is used as a cutoff to distinguish background noise from foreground. I know how to apply this value to the image of the nuclei to see what effect the cutoff has, but I would like to apply the threshold to a mesh plot. By chance does anyone know how to do this I cannot post images yet but I have added example code of my image analysis

[example image of nucleus](http://www.flickr.com/photos/109364616@N08/)

```
% First I load image
i = imread('nucleus.tif')
% I calculate the value of the threshold using my algorithm using my function
ci99 = getCI99('nucleus.tif')
% say for example that the calculated value is 100. I would apply this threshold to the image of the nucleus with the following command
imshow(picture , [ 100, inf]) % The resulting image only shows pixels at and above the calculated threshold.
```

I use the following code to make a mesh plot of a nucleus

```
% Mesh Plot
I=imread('nucleus.tif');
[x,y]=size(I);
X=1:x;
Y=1:y;
[xx,yy]=meshgrid(Y,X);
i=im2double(I);
figure;mesh(xx,yy,i);
colorbar
figure;imshow(i)
```

I am trying to apply the cutoff to the mesh plot analogous to the way I apply the threshold to the original image.

I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out the [Matlab clim function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/axes-color-limits--the-clim-property.html)

you should be able to do this with:

```
clim([min_threshold max_threshold]);
```

you can also access particular plots by holding on to axis handles (kinda like pointers)

```
fig1 = figure;
ax1  = mesh(xx,yy,i);
colorbar;

fig2 = figure;
ax2  = imshow(i);

set(ax1, 'clim', [100, inf]);
```

holding on to the axis handles lets you set parameters on any plot at any time, rather than only dealing with the last one you were working with.

Last note: try the image function rather than imshow. its not exactly the same thing, but you might find that you don't need to use the image processing toolbox at all.

Comment: I appreciate your response Potter. When I try using the code that you suggested I get the following error: Error using set
Bad property value found.
Object Name: surface
Property Name: 'CLimInclude'.